# Why is Sibelius causing audio crackling from the internal speakers of the 2023 M3 Max 16-inch MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, apple-silicon, speakers, macos

I have recently completed the setup of a new 16-inch MacBook Pro with M3 Max (14/30 core distribution).

Today, for the first time, I noticed that the notification sound from the Mail and Messages apps came out distorted and crackling from the main, internal speakers (no Bluetooth audio connection nor wired external speakers).

Thinking it a general problem, I tried to reproduce some music, from a notational software (Sibelius). The audio was just perfect. Then I launched Music, or a YouTube video, and the crackling even grew louder and more annoying.

Quitting Sibelius apparently restored everything to normality.
I am aware that Sibelius is not native for Apple Silicon, but what is actually happening here? What is causing this audio issue? What can be done? I work with this software.

Edit, adding results from further testing:

1. updated to macOS 14.2.1
2. with no app running, tested audio in System Settings, then a full song in Apple Music, then a YouTube video in Safari. All played back well
3. Launched Sibelius, played a score with NotePerformer as audio unit. Played back well, no issues
4. Switched to Apple Music, played back a song. After 5-6 seconds, cracks start appearing in the audio.
5. Quit Sibelius, waited 15 secs to allow audio engines to fully offload, switched to Apple Music, played back same song. No crackles.
6. Repeated steps 3-5 with Dorico, with same results
7. Repeated steps 3-5 with Sibelius on General MIDI (no NP). Same results, but crackling appears after 10-11 seconds, and is less frequent, though still there.
8. Repeated steps 3-5 with Dorico on Halion Basic (the top Playback Template, which should correspond to General MIDI). Same results as step 7.

Comment: Quick test - Audio Midi Setup [Apps/Utilities] toggle the output format for your output device, either 44 to 48 or vice versa. It often doesn't matter which you choose, just swapping can jog its elbow.

Comment: I swapped to 48 from 44. Tested again. While Sibelius (or Dorico, sigh) is running, the audio of other apps crackles...
If I then switch back to 44 it goes away for a few seconds, then come back.

Comment: Does Dorico use Apple's sound manager or ASIO? [I don't actually use Dorico, or Sibelius… or have an M3… so a bit of guesswork going on, from an old Cubase user of 35 year's experience;)) Cubase you can tell to drop ASIO when backgrounded & hand back to the system, I'm wondering if Dorico can do the same.

Comment: In Dorico's Preferences > Play > Device Setup, it says:
ASIO Driver: Built-In Audio.
In the Advanced Options below there is the possibility to uncheck the checked option Enable ASIO Guard.

I wonder where to look for this in Sibelius though...

Comment: Just to say that I run Dorico on an M1 Pro 16" MBP, and a M2 Pro Mac Mini, with no crackling; and it's certainly not a common complaint on the Dorico forums. And I don't think it's expected with Sibelius, either. Firstly, make sure that everything is set to the same sample rate. Do you have anything like AudioHijack -- particularly an old version - installed? Test the problem in a brand new user account, to see if you've migrated something that doesn't play nice with the new Mac. You could also try creating an Aggregate Device in Audio MIDI Setup, which just contains your internal speakers.

Comment: It could conceivably be a hardware problem, if this is a brand new Mac. :-( Also test in Safe Boot mode.

Comment: This happens only when either Sibelius or Dorico (or both) are running. If they’re not running, then audio is fine. Also, when they’re running, their audio is fine, everything else is crackling. I’ve not migrated, it’s brand new, everything fresh installed, no audio plugin. How do I check good sample rate?

Comment: In Dorico, Edit > Device Setup has the audio output and sample rate. Check that this is the same as what you have in Audio MIDI Setup.app. If one is 48k and the other at 44.1k, then that can cause problems. Don't know about Sib, but it will have a similar dialog. You could also increase the buffer size in Dorico. (Same place.) Also check Activity Monitor, seeing if anything is hammering the CPU, RAM, or Disk.

Comment: Though it's weird that notation app settings would affect *other* apps.

Comment: CPU, RAM, SSD, all very cool (this is an M3 Max with 36GB of memory, and I didn't have these issues with the Intel Mac, though it's on another macOS). I've also DM'd you.